# how to use In Memory Caching for User permissions

Tags: asp.net-core

In every request, I check whether the user has access to the desired action and controller or not. This causes the system to slow down. I want to use In Memory Caching to place the action table in the temporary memory, and in the first request, the action table will be placed in the temporary memory. So that I can check the access with the list in the temporary memory.

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public UserPolicy(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }


    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserPolicyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var request = _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request;
        string actionName = request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
        string controllerName = request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString();

        if (token != "")
        {
            var t = handler.ReadJwtToken(token.Replace("Bearer ", "")) as JwtSecurityToken;

            var userId = t.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "userId").Value;

            if (dbContext.userAccessActions.Any(a => a.UserId == userId && a.ActionName == actionName && a.ControllName == controllerName))
           
                // اگر کاربر لاگین شده به اکشن مورد نظر دسترسی داشت.

                context.Succeed(requirement);
                else
                    //اگر دسترسی نداشت
                    context.Fail();
          
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: Hi I'm not very sure but it looks like a jwt authentication issue, could you pls check if [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) help you? I mean the should the token be validated by the middle automatically and we don't need to create a filter to handle it?

Comment: When I get the userId from the token, I can see in the userAccessActions table that the user has access. This class works correctly, but I want to store the userAccessActions table in the cache so that the search in the table can be done faster.

Comment: if (dbContext.userAccessActions.Any(a => a.UserId == userId && a.ActionName == actionName && a.ControllName == controllerName))

Comment: I mean this code

Comment: sorry I still can't understand your requirement.. let's wait someone else to share their ideas..